# How can I use my getter for a computed property?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a simple Vuex Store using Vuex module decorators

```
@Module
export default class WorkoutModule extends VuexModule {

    _workout: Workout;

    @Mutation
    startWorkout(workout) {
        this._workout = workout;
    }

    get workout() { return Workout; }

}
```

How can I use my getter for a computed property? I tried this:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['workout'])
},
```

But thats not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set namespace. For example, in vuex-class you will type smth like this `const foo = namespace('foo')`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure where I exactly have to set the namespace, do you know any documentation about this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class). You should point your namespace in component, but before you should give name to your vuex module. Official doc should help, if you'll have problem with that.